# Calling js function from an iframe when user scrolls to the iframe or when the iframe is in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, iframe, geolocation

My website provides iframe code which is put in some other websites.

For simplicity lets say my domain i.e the source of the iframe is www.abc.com and my client who uses my iframe code has domain www.xyz.com.

In my iframe website I try to access geoLocation of user using javascript.

When www.xyz.com is browsed on mobile, www.abc.com (in iframe) puts a confirmation box to allow or deny the access for geoLocation.

Now my issue is:-

I want to show the confirmation box only when the iframe is in the viewable area of the browser. And I want to do it without asking my clients to put any more js code in their website. It should all happen from my iframe source.

I tried the following, but `visibilityChanged()` gets fired only when we change the browser tab or minimize or maximize the browser...

Sample code. a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onLoad() {
    console.log('onload:', (document.hidden));
    document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", visibilityChanged);
}

function visibilityChanged() {
    console.log('visibilityChanged: ',arguments);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
test
</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<iframe style="border:1px solid red; width:200px;height:200px;" src="a.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new PageVisibility API, which should be widely supported on mobile, looks much more promising:

- Broad support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility
- Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/

Code snippet from the spec (above):

```
   var timer = 0;
   var PERIOD_VISIBLE = 1000;
   var PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE = 60000;

   function onLoad() {
       timer = setInterval(checkEmail, (document.hidden) ? PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE : PERIOD_VISIBLE);
       if(document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", visibilityChanged);
   }

   function visibilityChanged() {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setInterval(checkEmail, (document.hidden) ? PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE : PERIOD_VISIBLE);
   }

   function checkEmail() { 
       // Check server for new messages
   }
```

Comment: Note that, per the caniuse.com notes, on Chrome, Opera, and on Android Browser (upcoming), it's 'document.webkitHidden' still, not just 'document.hidden'.

Comment: I tried with visibilitychange event but it seems to fire only when the browser tab is changed or browser window is minimized... it doesn't take effect when we scroll to the iframe.

Comment: Drilling in, it looks like that is unfortunately the expected behavior: "The User Agent MUST fire the visibilitychange event at the Document when the User Agent determines that the visibility of the Document contained by the top level browsing context has changed."
So if there is still no way in the DOM to check this, then the least painful way of doing x-site would be to have the host page use 'window.name': `window.name = { getPublicPositionInfo: function() {..}`

Comment: That is, if the `window.name` transport still works: See: http://bit.ly/1b3PoI6 . But I realize you may not be able to get the host page organization to add any of your code.